# CSS Overflow with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, overflow, css-position

I am trying to add a overflow scroll to jQueryUI draggable and resizable elements. Due to [bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6939) in jQuery UI, all resizable elements are absolute positioned by default and overflow does not work.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="object" style="top:10px;"></div>
   <div class="object" style="top:20px;"></div>
   <div class="object" style="top:30px;"></div>
   <div class="object" style="top:40px;"></div>
   <div class="object" style="top:50px;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:#000000;
    top:0px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.object{
    position:absolute;
    height:5px;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    left:100px;
    width:50px;
}
```

Is it possible to add overflow scroll to container with absolute positioned divs?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/es9dc/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, use `position: relative;` on the parent container

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/es9dc/6/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/es9dc/8/)

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:#000000;
    top:0px;
    overflow:scroll;
    position: relative;
}
```